# Where to download ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, download, sdk, edn

I have a [EDN](http://edn.esri.com) subscription, but I just can't find where I can download ArcGIS 9.3.1 software (specifically the ArcGIS desktop and the SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check at [https://customers.esri.com](http://customers.esri.com)

If your company have partnership you can also check at http://partnerportal.esri.com

Comment: I can find only ArcGIS 10 software at https://customers.esri.com , not 9.3.1 (or any other earlier version for that matter.)

Comment: Do you have subscription for 9.3.1 ? or only for 10.0 ? It will be better to contact your esri distributor.

Comment: So I need a license for each version?

Comment: Hm, as I can remember from my experience - when we bought EDN 10.0 we were not given license for 9.3.1

Comment: I think you do require a different licence because they changed how the licence manager works and how the program is registered between 9.3 and 10

Comment: So I need a license for each version? yes